# Предлог «на» в названиях стихотворений

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, названия, поэзия

В названиях стихов иногда используют предлог «на» («на смерть графа N» и т. д.).
Можно ли в иных случаях использовать этот предлог?
*Графу Штольцу, на его стихи и скульптуры*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Графу Штольцу, на его стихи и скульптуры*
А почему нет? Такое название вполне возможно.

Н. М. Карамзин:
Послание к Дмитриеву в ответ на его стихи, в которых он жалуется на скоротечность счастливой молодости

[П. А. Гвоздев](http://www.all-poetry.ru/lermontovu1.html):
Ответ Лермонтову на его стихи «На смерть Пушкина»

[В. С. Соловьев](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8D%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B8_(%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%91%D0%B2)):

```
                 РОДИНА РУССКОЙ ПОЭЗИИ  
           ПО ПОВОДУ ЭЛЕГИИ «СЕЛЬСКОЕ КЛАДБИЩЕ»
                   Посвящается П. В. Жуковскому
```

Название могло быть таким: *П. В. Жуковскому — на элегию «Сельское кладбище»*.

А. С. Пушкин. Царскосельская статуя (из цикла «Анфологические эпиграммы»):

> Урну с водой уронив, об утёс её дева разбила.
> Дева печально сидит, праздный держа черепок.
> Чудо! не сякнет вода, изливаясь из урны разбитой;
> Дева, над вечной струёй, вечно печальна сидит.

Стихотворение посвящено фонтану [«Девушка с кувшином»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC) (Екатерининский парк Царского Села, Санкт-Петербург; скульптор П. П. Соколов).
Название (или посвящение) совершенно спокойно могло выглядеть таким образом:
*П. Соколову, на его фонтан* [скульптуру] *«Девушка с кувшином».*

**Дополнение**

Можно не только "на что", но и "на кого". Вот интересное название:
*На прославителя русских героев, в сочинениях которого нет ни начала, ни конца, ни связи* ([эпиграмма](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B2,_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0,_%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B0,_%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8_(%D0%96%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)) В. А. Жуковского).